# Is there any way where Automation anywhere can be used as a credentials vault to store and fetch credentials using python

Tags: python, automationanywhere

In my project, Automation anywhere setup is already in use.
Hence is there any way by which i can push and pull credentials using a Python script From 'AA'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  oauthlib by installing it 'pip install oauthlib'
You can use it to store credential in local file system and even refresh credential and validate it.

Comment: Yes you are right, But here am checking feasibility with Automation Anywhere.

Comment: I am using it for all type of auth. Ok np